# Clear screen (^l) to last prompt

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, tmux, suckless-terminal

Macosx's terminal has a behavior that it would clear screen to previous user prompt instead of clear the whole screen. I'm using st terminal and tmux, how we can achieve that behavior?

Comment: Is that Ctrl-l? I don't see this behaviour on Terminal.App with default or homebrew bash. The entire screen gets cleared (or, well, the text is pushed off-screen).

Comment: Sorry, that's `command+L` that will clear previous user prompt, `ctrl-L` in macosx still clear the whole screen. How to have same `command+L` behavior? I don't find any terminal that support this feature, or a patch. Thanks @muru